# If someone dropped a conventional bomb on a stellerator, what would happen?

Tags: estimation, plasma-physics, fusion, explosions

Let's say we have a [stellarator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellarator) outputting a steady 200 GW of electrical power. If someone dropped a conventional bomb / explosive / shell on it that was just enough to breach plasma containment, how much energy would be released, and what would the aftermath of this be? Assume a worst case scenario. Additionally, will any dangerous chemicals be released into the atmosphere?

I'm trying to compare this to a similar scenario in a typical nuclear power plant. My guess is that the plasma will quickly dissipate and there will be no large radius of destruction beyond what a conventional bomb could do, and that no radiation or dangerous chemicals will be released - but I have no idea how to even approach this sort of question.

Comment: Yeah, fusion reactors are not good bombs or terrorist threat targets because there's virtually no fallout or any huge environmental impact.  More damage would be done by the initial bomb than any subsequent results from the failure of the reactor...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an excellent description of the accident risks associated with a fusion reactor at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_power#Accident_potential). In summary:

- There is no risk of a meltdown or runaway reaction
- Sudden failure of magnetic containment could lead to a rapid fragmentation of the containment vessel, but this risk is already understood through experience with MRI machines
- Release of flammable hydrogen co0lant into the atmosphere could cause a small chemical explosion
- Approximately 1kg of tritium and other radioactive gases could be released into the atmosphere, but this would quickly disperse

Comment: Thank you, that is an excellent answer. The only thing that I'm missing is an estimation of how powerful the explosion might be.